# Laravel 5, can't get the ID of the just saved model, when using UUID

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, uuid

I'm using Laravel Eloquent for my posts table and using the UUID for my table's primary key. But after saving the model I can't get the ID from it, although all the values are correctly inserted in database.

```php
$post = new App\Post();
$post->uuid  = \Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid::generate();
$post->save();
dd($post->uuid); //return null or 0
```

Adding accessors or using `$post->getKey()` could not solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have an accessor for `uuid`?

Comment: @Hkan adding accessor did not help.

Comment: Are you sure that the generated `uuid` is correctly saved to database? Also, just **before** the `$post->save()`, what does `dd($post->uuid)` print?

Comment: @Hkan yes the generated UUID is correctly saved to db. calling $post->save() before printing uuid results this error:Object of class Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid could not be converted to int

Comment: try `dd($post->getKey(), $post->getKeyName())`

Comment: $post->getKey() also could not solve the problem,I still get 0

Comment: What is the type of `uuid` field in your database ?

Comment: @Salar modify `\Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid::generate()` as `\Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid::generate()->string`

Comment: @Hkan uuid is a 128 bit string. I'm sure the problem is not with the uuid package because the data is stored in db correctly or my model can be retrieved after being saved, the question is that why just after saving I cant get the uuid

Comment: @Salar I'm not sure but I read the source of that package, and `generate()` method returns a `\Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid` object, and not a string.

Comment: Agree with @Hkan : https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid/blob/master/src/Webpatser/Uuid/Uuid.php#L139

Comment: It does return a string, there's a __toString() at the bottom which returns `$this->string`

Comment: Btw, as requested by zorx, what is the output of `$post->getKeyName()` ? Besides that, how is your uuid field in the db table defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Laravel API documentation, Eloquent Models have a boolean property `$incrementing` which indicates if the IDs are auto incrementing. To use UUIDs in our models we have to set this variable to false like this:

```php
public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: But after doing this we can't access to id property